# How to upload travis artifacts to S3 only in develop branch

Tags: git-branch, travis-ci

I've read [this blog post](http://about.travis-ci.org/blog/2012-12-18-travis-artifacts/) that explains how to configure travis to upload build artifacts to S3. How do I limit the "travis-artifacts upload" command to work only in the "develop" branch? I still want the branches to run CI, I just don't want them to overwrite the build artifacts uploaded by the develop branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend the command to check for the branch name:

```
after_success:
  - test ${TRAVIS_BRANCH} = develop && travis-artifacts upload
```